# How to change the style of an ant.design 'Table' component?

Tags: html-table, classname, antd

I have a table at the moment and I want to change the column headers of the tables to a different color.

[link to table](https://user-images.githubusercontent.com/24757872/39104365-d5b5830a-4675-11e8-861c-5b4e82e41262.png)

### Things I've tried:

1. ```
   <Table className="ant-table-thead">
    ...
   </Table>
   ```
2. ```
   <Table className="ant-table-content">
   ...
   </Table>
   ```

### Inside of a css file, I put:

```
.ant-table-content {
  background-color: rgb(127, 127, 127);
  color: rgb(127, 127, 127);
 }
```

I would love some help styling this particular Table component, but if you could also give me a general guideline (or somewhere I could find all of the possible className) of how to style other components in ant.design, it would be much appreciated.

Comment: Have you tried styling the <th> element itself?

Comment: sorry, I forgot to include that I tried styling the table component using `style={{background: rgb(127, 127, 127)
  color: rgb(127, 127, 127)}}`

Comment: Hey, @Hunter690 did you achieve this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

so I found out that the general idea was right. For each html component like the Table, it's common practice to define a className. Because I'm using Ant-Design, I have to have specific classNames. These classNames can be found in the node_modules folder in client, inside antd/es and whatever specific component in use. Then, the index.css file lists out all of the classNames and the specific attributes that are editable.

Comment: Is there an example of this?

Answer (score 0):

You could also modify antd styling by overriding the default.less attributes.  But for that you would need to use less instead of css.  The documentation would have more details.

1. `import 'antd/dist/antd.less'`
2. You would need to have a less loader in your webpack.
3. Also create a theme reference in package.json that points to a .js files
   that has the overrides.

   ```
   "theme": "./theme.js"
   ```
4. Write the overrides in the `theme.js` file.

```
module.exports = () => 
{
    return {
        'primary-color': '#1DA57A',
        'border-radius-base': '2px',
    }
}
```